# Converting arrays to string in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to add the values that comes off from my database using the method `COUNT`; the method works well and is using an array to give me the proper count. Now I am trying to add the values that this code blocks are coming up:

```
$VALUE1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(COLUMN) FROM TABLE");
$VALUE1PRINT = mysqli_fetch_array($VALUE1);
$VALUE2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(COLUMN) FROM TABLE");
$VALUE2PRINT= mysqli_fetch_array($VALUE2);
```

I print the value from these arrays using this code block:

```
echo $VALUE1[0];
echo $VALUE2[0];
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to add the values from `VALUE1` & `VALUE2` and I've tried the following functions:

`Implode` :

```
$ARRAYTOSTRING=implode($VALUE1);
```

This method returns the data in this manner: If `VALUE1` is `1`, and `VALUE2` is `2`, it returns `11` and `22`, thus when added, it will return `33`. which is wrong because obviously, I need `3`. 
 
`Serialize` :

```
$ARRAYTOSTRING=serialized($VALUE1);
```

My `COUNT` method returns the number of rows or data that my database has, IE:
`1` or `2`.. etc. etc.; I want the values to add up, IE: If `VALUE1` is `1` and `VALUE2` is `2`, `1+2` and come up with a result, in this example, `3`.

Comment: 1. Show what you've tried. 2. Show an example of your data and expected results.

Comment: Have you tried this?
$totalofvalues = $VALUE1[0] + $VALUE2[0];

Comment: @Polaris Totally works! Short and very informative, SO needs more people like you. (Oh, and can you post your answer below so I can pick it, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

The below should work as commented:

```
$totalofvalues = $VALUE1[0] + $VALUE2[0];
```

Thanks